# dplyr: correlations with NA

Tags: r, dplyr

```
xx <- data.frame(group = rep(1:4, each=100), a = rnorm(100) , b = rnorm(100))
xx[c(1,14,33), 'b'] = NA
```

I'm trying to calculate correlations by group but I'm getting an error when there are NAs.

```
library(dplyr)
xx %>% group_by(group) %>% summarize(COR=cor(a,b,na.rm=TRUE))
    
Error: Problem with `summarise()` column `COR`.
    i `COR = cor(a, b, na.rm = TRUE)`.
    x unused argument (na.rm = TRUE)
    i The error occurred in group 1: group = 1.
    Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Comment: You can't do `na.rm=TRUE` with `cor`. As you are calculating the correlation of two columns (rather than a correlation matrix), you can do `use='complete'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `na.rm` argument in `cor`, it is `use`.  According to `?cor`, the usage is

> cor(x, y = NULL, use = "everything",
> method = c("pearson", "kendall", "spearman"))

> use - an optional character string giving a method for computing covariances in the presence of missing values. This must be (an abbreviation of) one of the strings "everything", "all.obs", "complete.obs", "na.or.complete", or "pairwise.complete.obs".

```
library(dplyr)
xx %>%
   group_by(group) %>%
   summarize(COR=cor(a,b, use = "complete.obs"))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 × 2
  group   COR
  <int> <dbl>
1     1 0.166
2     2 0.190
3     3 0.190
4     4 0.190
```

---

If there are groups with all NA, then use `"na.or.complete"` (updated data in the comments with groups having only NA)

```
xx %>%
    group_by(group) %>%
    summarize(COR=cor(a,b, use = "na.or.complete"))
# A tibble: 5 × 2
  group     COR
  <int>   <dbl>
1     1  0.0345
2     2 -0.397 
3     3  0.150 
4     4  0.376 
5     5 NA
```

which returns the same with an `if/else` condition and using `"complete.obs"`

```
xx %>%
    group_by(group) %>%
    summarize(COR= if(any(complete.cases(a, b)))
     cor(a,b, use = "complete.obs") else NA_real_)
# A tibble: 5 × 2
  group     COR
  <int>   <dbl>
1     1  0.0345
2     2 -0.397 
3     3  0.150 
4     4  0.376 
5     5 NA
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun. What if there is a group with just NA: `xx <- data.frame(group = rep(1:5, each=10), a = rnorm(50) , b = c(rnorm(40),rep(NA,times=10))); xx[c(1,14,33), 'b'] = NA`. I get the error: `Error: Problem with summarise() column COR. i COR = cor(a, b, use = "complete.obs"). x no complete element pairs i The error occurred in group 5: group = 5. Run rlang::last_error() to see where the error occurred.`

Comment: @HappyPy change the use to `"na.or.complete"`